# docker compose issue on windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an opensource project cloned, and it has docker-compose.yml.
I execute

> docker-compose up

But I see error:

> ERROR: could not find plugin bridge in v1 plugin registry: plugin not found

I even tried a commonly mentioned solution on SO:

> docker network create --driver nat network-name

But issue still persists.

I understand that docker-compose is part of docker desktop install on windows.

How to solve it?

Content of the file:

```
version: "3"

services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.7.0
    ports: ["9200:9200"]
    networks: ["sandbox"]
    environment: ["discovery.type=single-node"]

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.7.0
    ports: ["5601:5601"]
    networks: ["sandbox"]
    depends_on: ["elasticsearch"]

  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.7.0
    volumes:
      - ./config/logstash.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
    networks: ["sandbox"]
    ports: ["5000:5000/udp"]
    depends_on: ["elasticsearch"]

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:6.0.2
    volumes: ["./grafana/plugins/cinnamon-elasticsearch-app:/var/lib/grafana/plugins/cinnamon-elasticsearch-app"]
    ports: ["3000:3000"]
    networks: ["sandbox"]
    depends_on: ["elasticsearch"]

networks:

  sandbox:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Please share your docker-compose file.

Comment: Content of the file added to the question.